# Is there any third party tools to create multiple layouts in Android Instead of Different Layout Folder?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-resolution

I know that we have to manually manage multiple device resolutions when we create Android app.

Is there any third party framework in which when we create one device resolution, it automatically create layout for other device resolutions?

Please let me know.

Comment: I have lookin for such kind of tool .. tell me if you ll find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the `px` unit, Android uses `dip` units or **Device Independent Pixels** for rendering it's screen. The purpose of using `dip` is to ensure that you don't have to create layouts for different resolutions.

In the mobile space, we typically have only two kinds of layouts to be taken care of: 1) Phone 2) Tablet.

Then there is vertical and horizontal orientation layout which help you better control how the Android OS renders your app in these orientations.

[Supporting Multiple Screens on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) should be a good resource to start with.

**EDIT:**

Have you tried [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/)? Here's some other discussions regarding Android's layout tools: [Is there a good tool for doing Android layout design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783586/is-there-a-good-tool-for-doing-android-layout-design).

Android OS also comes bundled with some optimization tools like `HierarchyViewer`, `layoutopt` to improve your app's performance. More on [Layout Optimization](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#layoutopt)

On a more philosophical note, sometimes, what you maybe be looking for may not be what you really need: [Why you don’t really want a WYSIWYG layout editor for Android](http://designbycode.tumblr.com/post/1079612795/why-dont-wysiwyg-android)

Happy coding!

Do share your finds and accept the answer that works for you so others may find it useful during their stressful midnight searches :)

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the answer. I know that we must have to make the different layout to support Multiple screen supports in android. Now, I am searching that is there any ready made tool which can create the Layout for other screen size based on the just one screen resolution ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: See EDIT above for more details.

Comment: Thanks Man. It looks like something helpfull to make layout. But still wondering about to made layout for all screens.